# How to view or convert a .qph video file?

Tags: video, mp4, avi, data-recovery, mov

When I was transferring a video file, it got corrupted, which I got recovered.
The recovered video file is in .qph format, which I am unable to view/convert into any other format.

Please let me know if there is a way to convert it into mp4/mov/avi or any other format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wtf is a qph file?  I ask, only because it is pretty non-standard (I've literally written books on digital video, and I've never heard of it), and knowing anything about the format would aid in a solution.

Comment: I am also not sure about the qph format. But I got this file after recovering the corrupted file.

Comment: Whatever recovery tool you used broke the extension.  You should use a hex editor to pull the file magic (typically, the first 4 bytes of the file).  If the file is indeed intact, it may be as simple as changing the extension.  Some tools (VLC, I think) should infer the file type... which you could then use to determine what it is you actually have.